# Php forward request as is including post data and uploaded files

Tags: php

I’m trying to incrementally create a new version of an old api built with php.

What I’m trying to do is

1. Check if router can handle request
   -case no: redirects request to old api (old api in another server on local network)

Challenges I have is I want to forward request including any request body sent from client.

Current code:-

```
try{

Router->run()

}catch ( NotFound $e ) {

// forward request to old server

}

die();
```

I tried using curl but couldn’t make it respect multi file upload requests.

I also considered using 300 redirect headers but was not sure if all clients will be able to handle that gracefully. (Current api is consumed by web and mobile applications)

Which method is recommended in such use case ? Are redirect headers reliable ?
If not is there a good client lib that can help me achieve what I need ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the client need to know your new API forwards the request to the old API? Also, where does this `Router` thing come from? Did you make that class yourself?

Comment: What was your old api request method? do you need to support upload files ?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware no, and yes Router is my a class i wrote to automatically map requests to Controller->method.

Comment: @ttrasn old api supported post-get-put-patch-delete and yes i need file upload

Answer (score 1):

I think using a proxy is better than PHP handling, for example, something like this can pass requests to the old backend if catch 502 error in new server:

```
http {
  upstream new_api {
    server host:port;
  }

  upstream old_api {
    server host:port;
  }

  server {

    location / {
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      error_page 502 = @old_api;
      proxy_pass http://new_api;
    }

    location @old_server {
      proxy_set_header Host old.api.com;
      proxy_redirect https://old.api.com/ https://$http_host/;
      proxy_cookie_domain old.api.com $http_host;
      proxy_pass https://old_api;
    }
  }
```